# Segregate results from mongodb based on a particular field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

My schema for list collection is-

```
list:
    {
    username : "some username",
    listitem : "some item",
    category : "some category",
    status : "some status"
    }
```

db.list.find() gets all the results, but I want to retrieve data based on category where the results with same category value appear together.Here is sample output of

```
db.list.find()
```

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("585669eb4aa058f4e7972db3"),
        "username" : "user1",
        "listitem" : "item 1",
        "status" : "P",
        "category" : "A",
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5856a7c64aa058f4e7972db4"),
        "username" : "user2",
        "listitem" : "item 2",
        "status" : "p",
        "category" : "B",
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5858faedde3ffb11a083e770"),
        "username" : "user1"
        "listitem" : "item 3",
        "status" : "p",
        "category" : "A",
}
```

But I want all my 'A' category results together and 'B' category results together.

that is,output should be like this-

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5856a7c64aa058f4e7972db4"),
        "username" : "user2",
        "listitem" : "item 2",
        "status" : "p",
        "category" : "B",
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("585669eb4aa058f4e7972db3"),
        "username" : "user1",
        "listitem" : "item 1",
        "status" : "P",
        "category" : "A",
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5858faedde3ffb11a083e770"),
        "username" : "user1"
        "listitem" : "item 3",
        "status" : "p",
        "category" : "A",
}
```

Please someone tell me how to do this.Whether this directly possible through mongodb query or I have to perform operations to format output in this form, when I get result in node js server?

Comment: Can you share a sample output ? Do you mean that docs with same category are listed together but still as separate docs ?

Comment: I have added sample output.Please check! @rahulroc

Comment: It worked.Thank you so much! @shA.t

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple use case of sort

```
db.list.find().sort( { category: 1 } )
```

All the docs will be sorted by the corresponding `category` values and hence, all docs with the same category value will be listed together.